# Connecting to an on-premises SQL database from Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

How do I connect to a database on-premises from an Azure WebJob or an Azure Function? Is this even possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What makes you believe you *can't* connect to an on-premises database, given that it just needs a proper connection string. Does your on-prem environment allow for external access, or is it firewalled? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `How do I connect to a database on-premises from an Azure WebJob or an Azure Function? ` - Answer : A connection string with all/some checks on firewall

Comment: You'll need to use Hybrid Connection. See a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398205/azure-functions-connect-to-on-premises-sql-server

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and **what has been done so far to solve it**.

Comment: @brettsam - I don't know how you determined that a hybrid connection is needed: There is zero information about the on-premises environment that the OP is trying to connect to. For all we know, there's simply a firewall that can have a port opened.

Answer (score 1):

I've been recently researching this and have found there a 3 avenues to connect app services to on prem database, as of today anyway.

[Hybrid Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server), [VNET Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) or [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-intro)

The later 2 options require VPN or Express (I think) connectivity to a cloud VNET. The VNET Integration option requires a separate VNET with PointToSite gateway connecting to your existing VNET. The App Service Environment is a quite expensive option as your App Service Plan is actually hosted inside your VNET, no longer being a shared host.